# How can I convert seconds to this(23/08/2018 11:08:33 AM) format in javaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and it may be a simple query but I have searched a lot for this and did not get expected result.
My query is that How can I convert seconds to (DD/MM/YYYY H:M:S AM/PM) format in javascript.

I am getting below as response for time
1535004239

Please help me in this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: How about doing `new Date(1535004239)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Date` Object is always at the rescue. You are receiving the value 1535004239 in seconds. So first you need to convert it to milliseconds.

`var currentDate=1535004239*1000`

Next, you can pass the value as directly to the Date constructor.

`var date=new Date(currentDate)`

Thanks to some certain predefined functions of the Date object in ES5, you can now get your formatted Date using the `.toLocaleString()` function

```
var dateString=date.toLocaleString()
console.log(dateString)
```

The code above should output something like

`23/08/2018, 11:33:59`

**Edit 1**: Use the code below to exactly get your formatted output

Once you have the date in the `date` variable, to get the exact format you want, use the code below

`var currentDate= date.toLocaleDateString()+' '+date.toLocaleString('en-US', { hour: 'numeric', minute: 'numeric', second:'numeric', hour12: true })`

This should output something like `23/08/2018 11:33:59 AM`

Comment: Thanks Harshil .. Just help me more here by knowing that 
=> how can I remove the comma 
=> how can I make time as 12 hours format ?
Please let me know

Comment: @ChanchalS please check out the latest edit. Should clear all your queries.

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this using [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)

**This solution remove all timezone, every date is rapported to UTC**

`formatted` use 24H format instead of AM/PM

```js
let value = 1535004239
// multiply by 1000 to get milisecond
console.log(new Date(value * 1000))

let formatted = (new Date(value * 1000)).toISOString() 
formatted = formatted.replace("T", " ").replace(/\.?[0-9]*Z/, "")

console.log(formatted)
```

for 12H format (may not be correct as I never use it)

```js
function getFormattedDate(value) {
  let date;
  if (value) {
    date = new Date(value * 1000)
  } else {
    date = new Date()
  }
  let suffix = "AM"
  if (date.getUTCHours() > 12 || date.getUTCHours() === 0) {
    date.setUTCHours(date.getUTCHours() - 12)
    suffix = "PM"
  }

  let formatted = date.toISOString()
  formatted = formatted.replace("T", " ").replace(/\.?[0-9]*Z/, "") + " " + suffix

  return formatted;
}

console.log(new Date(1535004239 * 1000).toISOString() + " : " + getFormattedDate(1535004239))
console.log(new Date(1535148239 * 1000).toISOString() + " : " + getFormattedDate(1535148239))
console.log(new Date(1535030639 * 1000).toISOString() + " : " + getFormattedDate(1535030639))
console.log(new Date(1535028639 * 1000).toISOString() + " : " + getFormattedDate(1535028639))
console.log(new Date(1535155600 * 1000).toISOString() + " : " + getFormattedDate(1535155600))
console.log(new Date().toISOString() + " : " + getFormattedDate())
```

If you can use any format you want prefer the default [`Date.toString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString) as it gives informations about time zone

Comment: Thanks for the reply... can't we make it to 12 hrs format as my expected output is 23/08/2018 11:08:35 AM
And my current output after applying changes suggested above by you is : 2018-08-23 06:03:59

Comment: @ChanchalS edited. about the difference beetwen the date are your sure about your timestamp being `23/08/2018 11:08:35` ? because that doesn't seem possible since the last digit is the second digit of the seconds